# using mod_rewrite to redirect variables to a php file?

Tags: php, html

For my site let's say I have a file in a folder called 'download'

so the direct link for the file would be www.testing.com/download/file.exe

I want to throw an authorization token with it like so, .../download/file.exe?auth=asdffg122**, with the auth token being a hash from time and expiry. So far I have written in a .htaccess file :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule \(.*)$.(exe)$ check.php?file=$1?auth=$2 [QSA]
```

I want to pass the name of the file to variable $1, and the auth token to the $2 variable. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you expect the auth value to be generated inside the htaccess file?

Comment: no it would be generated when the link is created. I just want to pass the variables to the php file.

Comment: Or the real file name could be file.exe and then the download link would be file_dummy.exe?auth=**hash** .. and then just passing the file name and the hash into the php but the link looks like its linking to a direct file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*auth=(.*)\&*.*$
 RewriteRule ^.*\/(.*\.exe)$ check.php?file=$1&auth=%n
```

Assuming you add the auth= to the GET request
Edit: Modified based on comment from $@Orbling

Comment: The query string is stripped before entry to `RewriteRule`, so you can not match against it like that.  If matching is desperately needed, it can be matched on `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}` and the matching groups used in subsequent `RewriteRule` commands using `%n` substitutions (as opposed to `$n`).  The `[QSA]` tag appends the query string back on after the rewrite, combining it with anything you have added on the destination of the rule.

Comment: I don't necessarily need it matched, i just need it passed to the php file.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably wanted to, or should write is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.exe)$ check.php?file=$1 [QSA]
```

The leading `\` backslash should be a `^` start anchor, if you place that Rewriterule into the download folder. You can also only have one `$` end of subject marker (usually). To assert the file extension, move it into the parenthesis. The whole of `(.*\.exe)` becomes `$1`.

The `?auth=abc22` is automatically appended as `&auth=abc22` when you use `[QSA]`. So that adding a `$2` becomes redundant. (You would need a separate RewriteCond to match the QUERY_STRING anyway. It's not part of the rewrite path.)

See also [Serverfault: Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) for more examples.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so are you saying when (.*\.exe) is passed to $1 .. file.exe?auth=abc22 = $1?

Comment: Only the part until the `?` question mark becomes `$1`. The query string isn't seen by the RewriteRule. See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Rewrite for some details.

Comment: how would i go on writing a rewriterule for the query? Something like 

rewrite (^.\?)$  .. then passing that? or no? sorry for asking a lot of questions.. :/ lol

Comment: Google for `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ...` examples.